# Do action when vimeo video is end Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video

I am using Visual Composer on my Wordpress Web site, and I want to when my Vimeo video is done to go on another page using JavaScript.

I have this when I go to inspect element
https://player.vimeo.com/e6910ce0-b4c8-4bd5-9b14-d57ff40ad813">
So i tried this :

```
var aud = document.getElementByTagName("video");
aud.onended = function() {
    alert("The audio has ended");
};
```

and it does not working. So can someone help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [official Vimeo Javascript API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js). With this you can fire events after the video is finished. Something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on('ended', function() {
        console.log('ended the video!');
    });
</script>
```